# Disable Search Field For Non-logged in Users in an Angular 2 App

Tags: javascript, authentication, angular, typescript

I've set up a login component and view, and it's working as expected in terms of preventing users from visiting AuthGuard protected routes when they're not logged in. However, I also have a search bar on the home login screen (in fact it's on every page of the app). So, since it's not a route, but it is a component, how would I disable that for users who are not logged in?

Answer (score 0):

Basically in your authentication you want to add in some sort of flag that signifies a user as logged in. In my example I am using a boolean. So if the boolean is false, disable input. If the boolean is true (or user is logged in) then its no longer disabled. you will probably have to pass this flag as a service assuming that your auth is a separate component.

```
import {Component, NgModule, ViewChild} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <h2>login is "password"</h2>
      <input [value]="password" (input)="password = $event.target.value"> <button (click)="Authed()">login</button>
      <h2>search</h2>
      <input [disabled]="!Auth">
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  Auth: boolean;
  password = "";
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2';
    this.password = '';
  }

  onKey(event:any) { // without type info
    this.password += event.target.password;
    console.log(this.password);
  }

  Authed(){
    if(this.password === "password"){
      this.Auth = true;
    }
    else(){
      this.Auth = false;
    }

  }

}
```

here is a working plunker of what I am talking about [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/NJoAD9E5beO4Z14EH4Tf?p=preview)